# How can I change jslint(VS 2010 extension) to ignore files?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, jslint

I have js lint installed in Vs 2010 as a extension through the extension manager.

It finds lots of errors but they are all from external plugins or from the jquery library. I am not going to go and fix stuff in an external plugin or jquery file. So how can I get it to not check these files?

I am also wondering how can I get it to ignore checking href links. I am using asp.net mvc so my links are like this

```
<a href="/account/reg">reg </a>
```

So it can't find this path as it is the path to the controller action method not a file. So how can I get it to not look at these?

Thanks

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can exclude files (external plugins, jquery, etc.) from the JSLint validation process.

[image]

From [here](http://jslint4vs2010.codeplex.com/).

For the href issue, if you don't have any JS in your views, you could exclude those as well using the method above.

Comment: FYI. You have to use the Solution Explorer. This JS Lint entries don't appear in the Solution Navigator window context menus. Solution Navigator is part of the Productivity Power Tools extension from MSFT.

Comment: Doesn't seem to remember these settings so you have to do this step each time you restart VS. Is there a way to save this?

Comment: FYI: If you mark several files the option might not show. Instead mark one file at a time.

Comment: Just ensure each file selected is a .js file. You may have other files like .map in the directory.