# How can I stop the jslint plugin for vs2010 giving errors on jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jslint

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I change jslint(VS 2010 extension) to ignore files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5069136/how-can-i-change-jslintvs-2010-extension-to-ignore-files)

I have been using the jsLint plugin for a while but just now when I start a build it seems to be looking at every javascript file and the error count on (usually not my) javascript goes to over 1000.

Does anyone have any experiences with how to resolve this?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/q/5069136/1313143

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click on a JS file in Solution Explorer and select "Skip on Build"