# Get JSLint to skip/ignore folder

Tags: visual-studio, jslint

I've got JSLint installed on VS2012. I'm using the Tiny MCE plugin, which has javascript files scattered through dozens of subfolders. When I build, I get thousands of errors for these files. How do I tell JSLint to ignore the whole tinyMCE folder & its subdirectories? I can selecteach .js file and right-click "skip on build" - but not on folders.

Comment: Sorry -- I've got VS2010 installed, and a different version of the plugin (though I wonder if the 2012 version isn't a repackaged version of [this](https://jslintnet.codeplex.com/)).  Out of curiosity, is the right-click option [described here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5111850/1028230) present, maybe?

Comment: Hi @ruffin. The right click option works, but that has to be on individual files. The TinyMCE plugin has dozens & dozens of folders & subfolders. You can't right-click on a folder and do it. If I could just exclude the top level folder (and all subfolders), that would be dead easy - that's what I want. Otherwise I have to open every subfolder, select all (and only) the .js files, and do the right-click.